# iOS 4.2 DateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2

The following code worked in my app previous to iOS 4.2.

```
NSString *sunday = @"2011-03-13 20:15 -04:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:sunday];

NSLog(@"sunday: %@ myDate: %@ fromNow: %d", sunday, myDate, [myDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
```

Outputs:

```
sunday: 2011-03-13 20:15 -04:00 myDate: (null) fromNow: 0
```

What am I doing wrong here? `myDate` is `null`. Is there something about `dateFormmater` that changed and I'm missing. I imagine it's something trivial at this point as I've been staring at this...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, Z specifier parses both "-0400" and "GMT-04:00", not "-04:00". [UTS #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) seems to confirm it. In my tests, though, it even parsed "GMT-0400". So  "-04:00" does look like the only time zone format NSDateFormatter refuses to understand.

May I cynically suggest [Apple's bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/) as the answer?

Comment: NSDateFormatter previously understood it, iOS < 4. I've modified my API to return a timestamp. So looks like there's no real answer. I'm resolved that this is an iOS 4 bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting your dashes, eg:

```
  @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm Z"
```

My best reading here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns seems to suggest that this is actually required, though I seem to recall having used that same date formatting pattern in the past on iOS w/o issue.

Comment: Didn't work. From other posts this seems to be a iOS > 4 problem.